# How to update Firestore Rules with custom Roles

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, roles

How to configure RULES to control Reads/Writes and Deletes on a collection (RECORDS) based on custom user roles defined in another collection (USERS)?

---- User Collection  ----

```
USERS: {
    <RandomID1> : { uid: 234, email: "abc@xyz.com", role: "ENDUSER" },
    <RandomID2> : { uid: 100, email: "def@xyz.com", role: "ADMIN" }
}
```

---- Records Collection ----

```
RECORDS: {
    <RandomID1> : { uid: "234", name: "Record 123" },
    <RandomID2> : { uid: "234", name: "Record 456" },
    <RandomID3> : { uid: "999", name: "Record 999" } /* another user's record */
}
```

---- Current Rules ----

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Assuming the user is logged in the web application and using client-side Firebase SDK, how to achieve the below cases?

IFF: `USERS.RandomID1.role = 'ENDUSER'`

1. How to restrict the user to READ only their records from RECORDS,
   but not somebody else's?
2. How to restrict UPDATEs to only their
       records in RECORDS?
3. How to restrict DELETEs on all of their records in RECORDS?
4. How to restrict all CRUD operations on the rest of collections(/COLLECTION**), except RECORDS?

IFF: `USERS.RandomID1.role = 'ADMIN'`

5. How to enable this (Admin) user to perform all CRUD operations in
   RECORDS?

So, how to rewrite or update rules to control these operations? If not, are there better designs or alternatives?

*Note: We need to handle these cases to block some users/hackers who may try to open browser console/inspect window, and execute firestore queries with or without any conditions.*

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my final answer:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        //Rule on a Collection Groups, instead of simple Collection
        match /{NestedSubCollections=**}/<COMMON_COLLECTION-NAME>/{doc} {
            allow create: if isSignedIn() && isAdmin();
            allow read: if isSignedIn() && (isAdmin() || isThisUserRecord(resource.data.<CUST_USER-ID-FIELD>));
            allow update: if isSignedIn() && (isAdmin() || isThisUserRecord(resource.data.<CUST_USER-ID-FIELD>));
            allow delete: if isSignedIn() && isAdmin();
        }
        //Collection UserDB, to validate profile updates
        match /UserDB/{userId=**} {
            allow create: if isSignedIn() && isAdmin();
            allow read: if isSignedIn() && (isAdmin() || hasUserProfile(resource.data.<CUST_USER-ID-FIELD>));
            allow update: if isSignedIn() && (isAdmin() || hasUserProfile(resource.data.<CUST_USER-ID-FIELD>));
            allow delete: if isSignedIn() && isAdmin();
        }
        //Checking if user is signed-in
        function isSignedIn() {
            return request.auth != null;
        }
        //Checking user's admin status, without the context of accessing collection, but directly
        function isAdmin() {
            return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/UserDB/$(request.auth.uid)).data.<CUST_ROLE-FIELD> == "<ADMIN-ROLE-NAME>";
        }
        //Check whether a current record belong to logged-in user; by <CUST_USER-ID-FIELD>, not oAuth-ID
        function isThisUserRecord(custUserId) {
            return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/UserDB/$(request.auth.uid)).data.<CUST_USER-ID-FIELD> == custUserId;
        }
        //Check whether a logged-in user has existing profile or not
        function hasUserProfile(userOauthId) {
            return userOauthId == request.auth.uid;
        }
    }
}
```

It is working perfectly fine in my production application and everything is secured without writing a single line of code in the application!

How to test it?

1. Updated a user record in UserDB with <CUST_ROLE_FIELD>, and <ADMIN_ROLE_NAME> as value
2. Then go to your frontend web application, go to browser Console, and trying to hit Firestore queries and validate the records and results
3. If it's a non-admin user, then he can only Read/Update as per our rules above, and the other queries will fail as expected.
4. Note, the create/delete is performed in the backend, via cloud function, for security reasons.

In sum, admin can perform any action on all records, but non-admin users can only touch his own records with limited Read/Update operations only.

You may have to tweak a bit based on other use cases.  Let me know if anything.

Answer (score 1):

For 5 you will need to define [custom claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) for your admins, below I assume a field `isadmin` is set to true for admins.

The following rules should be a good start:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // 4: Will restrict all others access
    match /records/{recordid} {
      // 1+5(read): restrict reads       
      allow read: if request.auth != null
        && (resource.data.uid == request.auth.uid || request.auth.token.isadmin);
      // 2+3+5(write): +create as a bonus
      allow write: if request.auth != null
        && (request.resource.data.uid == request.auth.uid || request.auth.token.isadmin);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but defining custom claims is the extra overhead of designing its UI and additional work on the frontend side. My use cases are to handle completely in the backend.  Your rules did help me and I finished it with additional rules for all my cases.  I am posting it as another final answer.